# PayUmoney seamless Integration

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payumoney

experts
can you help me in seemless integration with PayUmoney payment Gateway in android
also if you have any sample of seemless integration please share

i have tried like this but showing me error of Marchentkey and salt is incorrect but i copied both from my account

below is code detail

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Payu.setInstance(this);
    proceedtopay();
}

public void proceedtopay(){

    PaymentParams mPaymentParams = new PaymentParams();

    String merchant_key="rjQUPktU"; // test gtkFFx XmOFYRT3
    String salt="e5iIg1jwi8"; // test eCwWELxi aTZEImxcYO
    mPaymentParams.setKey(merchant_key);
    mPaymentParams.setAmount("15.0");
    mPaymentParams.setProductInfo("Tshirt");
    mPaymentParams.setFirstName("Waseem");
    mPaymentParams.setEmail("waseemahmad241@gmail.com");
    mPaymentParams.setTxnId("0123479543689");
    mPaymentParams.setSurl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php");
    mPaymentParams.setFurl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf1("udf1l");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf2("udf2");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf3("udf3");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf4("udf4");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf5("udf5");

    String hashSequence = merchant_key+"|0123479543689|15.0|productinfo|Waseem|waseemahmad241@gmail.com|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||"+salt;
    String serverCalculatedHash= hashCal("SHA-512", hashSequence);
    mPaymentParams.setHash(serverCalculatedHash);
    mPaymentParams.setCardNumber("4012001037141112");
    mPaymentParams.setCardName("test");
    mPaymentParams.setNameOnCard("test");
    mPaymentParams.setExpiryMonth("05");// MM
    mPaymentParams.setExpiryYear("2020");// YYYY
    mPaymentParams.setCvv("123");
    mPaymentParams.setEnableOneClickPayment(1);

    PostData postData = null;
    try {
        postData = new PaymentPostParams(mPaymentParams, PayuConstants.CC).getPaymentPostParams();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (postData.getCode() == PayuErrors.NO_ERROR) {
        // launch webview
        PayuConfig payuConfig = new PayuConfig();
        payuConfig.setEnvironment(PayuConstants.STAGING_ENV);
        payuConfig.setData(postData.getResult());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PaymentsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.PAYU_CONFIG,payuConfig);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PayuConstants.PAYU_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // something went wrong
        Toast.makeText(this,postData.getResult(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



public static String hashCal(String type, String hashString) {
    StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
    MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        messageDigest.update(hashString.getBytes());
        byte[] mdbytes = messageDigest.digest();
        for (byte hashByte : mdbytes) {
            hash.append(Integer.toString((hashByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash.toString();
}
```

and MyWebview Activity is

```
PaymentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//String base_url="https://test.payumoney.in/_payment";
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras();
    PayuConfig payuConfig =bundle.getParcelable(PayuConstants.PAYU_CONFIG);
    WebView mWebView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 //   String url =//payuConfig.getEnvironment() == PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_ENV ? PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_PAYMENT_URL :PayuConstants.MOBILE_TEST_PAYMENT_URL;
    byte[] encodedData = EncodingUtils.getBytes(payuConfig.getData(), "base64");
    mWebView.postUrl(PayuConstants.TEST_PAYMENT_URL,encodedData);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity {

```
WebView webView;
Context activity;
int mId;
/*private String mMerchantKey ="your marchant key"
private String mSalt = "your salt key"*/    
private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
private String mProductInfo = "product name"; //Passing String only
private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
private String mServiceProvider = "";// "payu_paisa";
private String mSuccessUrl = "success url";
private String mFailedUrl = "failure url";
String MAM_ID = "mem_id";
String EMAIL = "email";
String ADD1 = "address_line1";
String ADD2 = "address_line2";
String REGION_ID = "region_id";
String CITY_ID = "city_id";
String PROMOCODE = "promocode";
String PIN_CODE = "pin_code";
String ADD_DATE = "add_date";
String PRICE = "price";
String CARD_DISCOUNT = "card_discount";
String PROMOCODE_DISCOUNT = "promocode_discount";
String TXNID = "tnx_id";
String DEVICE_ID = "device_id";
String PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
boolean isFromOrder;
/*
  Handler
 */
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Bundle bundle;
SharedPreferences spfs;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

/**
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_for_payumoney);
    spfs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);
    activity = getApplicationContext();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle("Payment Gateaway");

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.e("Bndle Data:- ", bundle.toString());
        mFirstName = bundle.getString("Name");//NAME
        mEmailId = bundle.getString("Email");// lOGIN IN PAYUMONEY ID
        mAmount = 1.0;//bundle.getDouble("Price");// AMOUNT
        mPhone = bundle.getString("Mobile"); // MOBILE ! REQUIRED
        mId = 1;//bundle.getInt("id");
        isFromOrder = true;// bundle.getBoolean("isFromOrder");

        Log.e("Tag payment ", "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);


        Random rand = new Random();
        String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

        mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

        mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                mTXNId + "|" +
                mAmount + "|" +
                mProductInfo + "|" +
                mFirstName + "|" +
                mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                mSalt);


        mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.payu.custombrowser.Bank");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
                Log.e("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
                Log.e("onReceivedError", "error code:" + rerr);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + rerr.getDescription().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            /*@Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                           SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {
                    RecepetUpload();

                } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                    Log.e("Payment STatus", "failure");
                    Custom_Toast.show(getApplication(), "Payment Transcation Failed");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Payment.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("status", false);
                    intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                    intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                    intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(Payment.this), "PayUMoney");

        /**
         * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
         */
        Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

        mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
        mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
        mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
        mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
        mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
        mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
        mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
        mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
        mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
        mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
        mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

        Log.e("Url WEb View", mAction);
        webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

/**
 * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
 *
 * @param webView
 * @param url
 * @param postData
 */
public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                              Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
    sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
        sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
    sb.append("</form></body></html>");

    Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}

/**
 * Hash Key Calculation
 *
 * @param type
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashSequence);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
    }
    Log.e("Hex String", "" + hexString);
    return hexString.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onPressingBack();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onPressingBack();
}

/**
 * On Pressing Back
 * Giving Alert...
 */
private void onPressingBack() {

    final Intent intent;

    if (isFromOrder)
        intent = new Intent(Payment.this, MainActivity.class);
    else
        intent = new Intent(Payment.this, MainActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Payment.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Payment Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://https://secure.payu.in"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.local/https/https://secure.payu.in")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Payment Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://https://secure.payu.in"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.local/https/https://secure.payu.in")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /**
     * Instantiate the interface and set the context
     */
    PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                mHandler = null;
                Toast.makeText(Payment.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void RecepetUpload() {
    final ProgressDialog progDialog;


    progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Payment.this, "", "waiting");
    try {

        if (!progDialog.isShowing()) {
            progDialog.show();
        }

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "http://www.local.com/club-app/api-order-details", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                Log.e("Payment Status:--", "Success , " + mTXNId);
                Custom_Toast.show(getApplication(), "Payment Transcation Success");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Payment.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("status", true);
                intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

                try {
                    if (progDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Log.e("res Payment", "" + response);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                if (progDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(MAM_ID, "" + spfs.getString("mem_id", ""));
                params.put(EMAIL, "" + mEmailId);
                params.put(ADD1, "" + bundle.getString(ADD1));
                params.put(ADD2, "" + bundle.getString(ADD2));
                params.put(REGION_ID, "" + bundle.getString(REGION_ID));
                params.put(CITY_ID, "" + bundle.getString(CITY_ID));
                params.put(PIN_CODE, "" + bundle.getString(PIN_CODE));
                params.put(ADD_DATE, "" + bundle.getString(ADD_DATE));
                params.put(PRICE, "" + mAmount);
                params.put(CARD_DISCOUNT, "" + bundle.getString(CARD_DISCOUNT));
                params.put(PROMOCODE_DISCOUNT, "" + bundle.getString(PROMOCODE_DISCOUNT));
                params.put(PROMOCODE, "" + bundle.getString(PROMOCODE));
                params.put(TXNID, "" + mTXNId);
                params.put(DEVICE_ID, "" + Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
                params.put(PRODUCT_ID, "" + bundle.getString(PRODUCT_ID));
                Log.e("Bndle Params:- ", params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeout = 60000;// 30 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (progDialog.isShowing()) {
            progDialog.dismiss();

        }
        Log.e("", " Exception Occurs - " + e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: thanku for replying can you please explain me or also do you have any sample

Comment: hi this is complete running code and i have using in my project just use this class according you and try , hope it's will help

Comment: Hi Imran i have custome UI like i will fill all card detail and process then how will i send to those pramater and where ?

Comment: Imran i am always getting key an salt error i copied test key and test salt from payUmoney account 

when i created account with email n number they provide me detail of test live key .i have not completed my profile yet like business detail and bank detail

Comment: hi, yes you can fill with custom form

Comment: mapParams.put("bankcode", params1.get("bankcode"));
        mapParams.put("pg", params1.get("pg"));
        mapParams.put("ccname", params1.get("ccname"));
        mapParams.put("ccnum", params1.get("ccnum"));
        mapParams.put("ccvv", params1.get("ccvv"));
        mapParams.put("ccexpmon", params1.get("ccexpmon"));
        mapParams.put("ccexpyr", params1.get("ccexpyr"));

Comment: PayUJavaScriptInterface  success method  never called any help ?